# WPF ListBox - Getting UIElement instead of of SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, selecteditem, uielement

I created a `ListBox` that has a `DataTemplate` as `Itemtemplate`.  However, is there an easy way to access the generated `UIElement` instead of the `SelectedItem` in codebehind?

When I access `SelectedItem`, I just get the selected object from my
`ItemsSource` collection. Is there a way to access the `UIElement` (ie. the
element generated from the `DataTemplate` together with the bound object)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for the [ItemContainerGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator) property. Each `ItemsSource` has an [ItemContainerGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator) instance. This class has the following method that might interest you: [ContainerFromItem(object instance)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem).

Once you have a handle to the `ListBoxItem`, you can go ahead and browse the logical and visual tree. Check out [Logical Tree Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.aspx) and [Visual Tree Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx).

Like Andy said in the comments, just because the item exists in your collection doesn't mean a container has been generated for it. Any kind of virtualizing panel scenario will raise this issue; UIElements will be reused across the different items. Be careful with that as well.

Comment: Note that just because an item has been added to the control, that doesn't mean that its UI container has been generated yet. Make sure to account for the case where there is no UI container yet.

Comment: I am writing in c# and WPF and this property doesn't appear under ListBox.ItemsContainer How do I get the instance for this listbox?

Comment: @size, do you have a solution for my question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148279/record-items-visible-to-user-in-listbox (+250 bounty)

Comment: Just for reference here is the full code I got working:
`var container = ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ListBox.SelectedItem) as FrameworkElement;
if (container != null) container.Focus();`

Answer (score 5):

*siz*, *Andy* and *Bodeaker* are absolutely right.

Here is how I was able to retrieve the textbox of the listbox's selected item using its handle.

```
var container = listboxSaveList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listboxSaveList.SelectedItem) as FrameworkElement;
if (container != null)
{
    ContentPresenter queueListBoxItemCP = VisualTreeWalker.FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(container);
    if (queueListBoxItemCP == null)
        return;

    DataTemplate dataTemplate = queueListBoxItemCP.ContentTemplate;

    TextBox tbxTitle = (TextBox)dataTemplate.FindName("tbxTitle", queueListBoxItemCP);
    tbxTitle.Focus();
}
```

(Note: Here, VisualTreeWalker is my own wrapper over VisualTreeHelper with various useful functions exposed)