# Is there a way to check if a combobox or listboxitem is visible on screen?

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem, visible

If a listbox has many items, is there a way (programatically) to check if an item is visible on screen.

For example, the listbox has 100 items, but only first 24 are shown of the screen, is there a way to check if a specific (say list[75]) is currently displayed or one should scroll to see it?

Comment: You could check the visibility property of the item right and count it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2d527831-43aa-4fd5-8b7b-08cb5c4ed1db/

Answer (score 0):

Check [Calculating number of visible items in ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830272/calculating-number-of-visible-items-in-listbox/43837145) and look for my post below.

I've seen to many complex answers that are not correct.

**Short answer: (listBox1.Height/ listBox1.ItemHeight)**