# ObservableCollection and ListBoxItem DataTemplate generation problem

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, listboxitem

Something strange is going on with ObservableCollection.

I have the following code:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<DisplayVerse> _display;
private readonly ListBox _box;

    private void TransferToDisplay()
    {
        double elementsHeight = 0;

        _display.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < _source.Count; i++) {
            DisplayVerse verse = _source[i];
            _display.Add(verse);
            elementsHeight += CalculateItemsHeight(i);
            if (elementsHeight + Offset > _box.ActualHeight) {
                _display.RemoveAt(_display.Count - 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(elementsHeight.ToString());
    }

    private double CalculateItemsHeight(int index)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = _box.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;
        return lbi != null ? lbi.ActualHeight : 0;
    }
```

What I am trying to do here is control how many items go into the ObservableCollection _display. Now, within this for loop you can see that elements are added until the total elements height (+offset) is greater than the listbox itself.

Now, this is strange, the elementsHeight equals 0 after this for loop. (CalculateItemsHeight returns 0 in all for loop iterations even though the lbi is not null) It seems that the UI elements defined in the datatemplate are not created...

Yet.

Now, if I put some MessageBoxes after the _display.Add(verse) you can see that the CalculateItemsHeight actually returns the height of an item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _source.Count; i++) {
    DisplayVerse verse = _source[i];
    _display.Add(verse);
    MessageBox.Show("pause"); // <----- PROBLEM?
    elementsHeight += CalculateItemsHeight(i);
    if (elementsHeight + Offset > _box.ActualHeight) {
        _display.RemoveAt(_display.Count - 1);
        break;
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(elementsHeight.ToString());
```

After I modify the for loop as shown, the last MessageBox **actually shows** the actual height for all processed elements.

My question is - **when are the UI elements actually created**? It seems that it was done somewhere during the MessageBox display. This behaviour is pretty strange for me, maybe it has something to do with threading, not sure.

Adding to the _display ObservableCollection obviously creates an item immediately, but not its visual elements (they are however added afterwards, I just don't know exactly when). How can I do this same behaviour without having to pop the message box up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This creates somewhat flickering effect for a fraction of second (as if loading items one by one), but actually suits my needs.

The point is to refresh the UI for an item before retrieving its height.

I have created an extension method:

```
    public static void RefreshUI(this DependencyObject obj)
    {
        obj.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded, (Action)delegate { });
    }
```

And then before retrieving the height, I refresh the UI.

```
private double CalculateItemsHeight(int index)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = _box.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;
        if (lbi != null) {
            lbi.RefreshUI();
            return lbi.ActualHeight;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was trying to get this to work and I found the ".UpdateLayout()" function, which works perfectly for me.  I realize that you're doing vertical and I'm doing horizontal, but here's my code, it's pretty simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems.ItemsIn.Count; ++i)
    {
        //CalculateItemsHeight(i);

        ListBoxItem abc = (lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lb.Items[i]) as ListBoxItem);
        abc.UpdateLayout();
        totalWidth += abc.ActualWidth;
    }
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The wpf layout engine won't have been through the layout and arrange pass so your listboxitems won't have been given a size yet. Sticking in the message box will allow the background threads that do this run. Try forcing a call to Measure() on your items before looking at their size.

Comment: Nope, calling Measure() didn't fix the problem. I guess I should temper with the UI thread, but I don't know which part to call on UI Thread or how.