# ItemsControl item, going out of view

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I have a `ScrollViewer` within which, I have an `ItemsControl`. The `ItemsControl` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. The `ItemsControl` has an `ItemTemplate`, where in I provide a `TextBox` to display the data.

The data is getting displayed correctly. I have added a popup to each of the `TextBox` to display additional data with the placement target being Top.

The problem I am facing is when I scroll if an item goes out of view, I need to hide the popup and display it again when the item appears.

I have subscribed to the scrollviewer's `ScrollChanged` event, but how do I get hold of the item / `TextBox` which is going out of scope to hide the popup?

Comment: Code samples would simplify this and would save all the theoretical "I have a .." sentences

Comment: first of all , an ItemsControl incorporates it's own ScrollViewer , 
secondly have a look here at the last answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397780/scrollviewer-indication-of-child-element-scrolled-into-view

Comment: This seems to be a popular request recently!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method from the [Determining the Visibility of Elements inside ScrollViewer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/01/18/elements-visibility-inside-scrollviewer.aspx) article on Lester's WPF\SL Blog to determine whether a particular item is visible in the `ScrollViewer` or not. From that blog:

```
// position of your visual inside the scrollviewer    
GeneralTransform childTransform = ContainedObject.TransformToAncestor(ScrollViewerObj);
Rect rectangle = childTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0,0), 
    ContainedObject.RenderSize));

// Check if the elements Rect intersects with that of the scrollviewer's
Rect result = Rect.Intersect(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), ScrollViewerObj.RenderSize), 
    rectangle);

// if result is Empty then the element is not in view
if (result == Rect.Empty)
{
    ContainedObject.IsPopupOpen = false; // <<< Close relevant popup here
}
else
{
    //obj is partially Or completely visible
    //skip or bring obj in view.
}
```

Clearly, for this to work, you'll need to add a new `bool IsPopupOpen` property to the data object that is data bound to the `TextBox.Text` properties. You'll then need to `Bind` this to the `Popup.IsOpen` property too:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}" StaysOpen="False" ... />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

The `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event will get called very often when a `ScrollViewer` is scrolled. It would indeed be unwise to perform any code directly in that event handler, however the `ScrollChangedEventArgs` object has some properties that can help us. Please take a look on the [`ScrollChangedEventArgs` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollchangedeventargs.aspx) page on MSDN for full details of these properties.

There are two properties that you will have access to in your event handler named `VerticalChange` and `HorizontalChange` that should show you how much the `ScrollViewer` has been scrolled since the last event. [Now it's been a while, so I can't guarantee that they are the correct properties, but if you use the example code from the [`ScrollChangedEventArgs.VerticalChange` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollchangedeventargs.verticalchange.aspx) page on MSDN in your event handler, the read out should give you a clue as to which are the correct properties to use.]

So, having found the relevant properties, you can use them in your handler to determine whether to perform your code or not... try something like this:

```
double totalVerticalChange = 0.0;
double minimumValue = 24.0; // set this to whatever you want as a minimum scroll value
...
private void ScrollViewer_Changed(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (totalVerticalChange + e.VerticalChange >= minimumValue)
    {
        totalVerticalChange = 0.0;
        // perform your functionality here
    }
    else totalVerticalChange += e.VerticalChange;
}
```

Please forgive me if there are errors here as I can't check this in Visual Studio at the moment, but hopefully you get the idea... essentially, it's like we are 'filtering' out some of the events.

Comment: to get ContainedObject 
he would have to iterate the entire visual items of he's ItemsControl.

Comment: @eranotzap, I didn't see any improvements in the answers in your linked post which actually answers the opposite problem of items being scrolled *into* view, but please feel free to provide a better answer.

Comment: @Sheridan, you just change the test for negative instead of positive. Now for all items that are not visible, you disable the popups and do whatever else you want to do.

Comment: @Sheridan I really do not know how to thank you! your code snippet works, thanks for the link as well. I have an attached behavior, so I can figure an approach for showing / hiding the popup. Cheers man..

Comment: @Sheridan I have one doubt. Ihave handled, ScrollChanged event, but this event handler, is getting called many a time, thus causing some delay in the process. Have I done something wrong ?

Comment: @Sheridan I have a different approach, by which I fixed this scrolling issue, in my attached behavior where I am handling scrollchange, I check whether the corresponding popup associated with the control is open or whether the control is focused. If not, I am returning and bypassing the TransformToAncestor code, this works as of today .. Thanks for your superb answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that with us... it may help future users.

Comment: @Sheridan pleasure is mine!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397780/scrollviewer-indication-of-child-element-scrolled-into-view) which discusses determining the viewability of an object in a ScrollViewer.

The basic helper method:

```
private bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
    if (!element.IsVisible)
        return false;

    Rect bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    Rect rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
    return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
}
```

and an example function that does what you want to do:

```
private void Scroll_Changed(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Object o = sender;
    bool elementIsVisible = false;

    foreach (FrameworkElement child in this.stackPanel1.Children)
    {
        if (child != null)
        {
            elementIsVisible = this.IsUserVisible(child, this.scroller);

            if (!elementIsVisible)
            {
                // Logic to disable popups here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```