# ScrollViewer notify on RequestBringIntoView

Tags: wpf, virtualization, scrollviewer, routed-events

I am attempting to get notified when an element is scrolled into view ,

As i understand it , ScrollViewer calls BringIntoView on it's child elements and then 
  the child elements raise a RequestBringIntoView event which the ScrollViewer later catches 
  and handles.

This is done by Registering a Class handler for this Event and catching it as it bubbles up

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ScrollViewer), RequestBringIntoViewEvent, new RequestBringIntoViewEventHandler(OnRequestBringIntoView));
```

[ScrollViewer Source Code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ScrollViewer@cs/4/ScrollViewer@cs)

What i need is to get notified each time this process takes place , my attempt is to derive from 
  ScrollViewer and Create my own event of type and approach it in one of 2 ways :

1) Add a class handler for that same event with a true at the end for handling Handled events .

2) Creating my own event which handles events of  type RequestBringIntoViewEvent

```
public class NotifyOnBringIntoViewScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    static NotifyOnBringIntoViewScrollViewer()
    {
        // for secnario (2) replace RequestBringIntoViewEvent with Noti
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(NotifyOnBringIntoViewScrollViewer),RequestBringIntoViewEvent , new RequestBringIntoViewEventHandler(OnRequestBringIntoView), true);                       
    }


    public static readonly RoutedEvent NotifyBringIntoViewEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
                "NotifyBringIntoView", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RequestBringIntoViewEventHandler), typeof(NotifyOnBringIntoViewScrollViewer));

    private static void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // notify ..
    }
}
```

The handler is never reached , for one or tow reasons ,

1) I miss understood the way routed events works in regard to registering handlers .
2) My child elements never raise RequestBringIntoView , my attempt for this is as follows :

cs :

```
   public List<int> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<int>
            {
                1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
            };
        }
    }
```

xaml :

```
  <local:NotifyOnBringIntoViewScrollViewer>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <VirtualizingStackPanel />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                
       </ItemsControl>
    </local:NotifyOnBringIntoViewScrollViewer>
```

FYI : VirtualizingStackPanel  , i put this because i wasn't sure that this is the default panel 
      and if with out Virtualizing BringIntoView is ever called , since they are already in view.

Comment: my earlier question on the matter got some good responses and an alternative i wanted to avoid since it envoles traversing all the child elements of the scroll viewer on each scroll changed , 

I also got a suggestion by @ouflak which brought up this question 
where he suggested creating my own event.

Comment: You need any kind of interaction with items. Click into any item and you will get your event. You have to be doing something with the items or using items inside the scrollviewer to trigger that event.

Comment: No. I think you had a similar question somewhere here. Just that time I thought you need an event which will be fired on every item when you have any kind of interaction with that item inside ScrollViewer. I suggested you BringIntoView. Now I understand you wish to have event firing while you scroll, right?

Comment: @devhedgehog thanks that actually worked , but how would i imitate a sort of click on items when they are scrolled into view , 
i can't really on the user to click the items after scrolling.

Comment: @devhedgehog yes , but unlike scroll changed i want to be notified on which elements be became "Visible"

Comment: You shouldnt simulate any click on items. If you wish to get notifed when an item becomes visible then stop listening to BringIntoView but instead listen to IsVisibleChanged. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx

Comment: @devhedgehog ok ill try listening to IsVisibleChanged , i'll get back to you ,
thanks.

Comment: Ok, let me know about your progress

Comment: @devhedgehog IsVisibleChanged isn't a routed event , so i would need to hook every child to the handler.

Comment: Just attach a dependency property in style of your container that enableds subscribing IsVisibleChanged to a static handler.

Comment: what container , i'm not quite following u , 
I'n my derived scrollviewer you wan't me to add a DP ,which would do what ?

Comment: Open new chat and pass link here.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39592/wpf-scrollviewer