# WPF Treeview Items Visibility Attached behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I'm writing a attached behavior

`public class resizingBehavior : Behavior<ItemsControl>`

to determine the number of visible items in a treeview.

In  OnAttached Method

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
   base.OnAttached();
   AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
}
```

Inside `AssociatedObject.Loaded` event handler

I'm hooking a size changed event handler for my treeview control

```
private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var itemsControl = (ItemsControl)sender;

   _sizeChangedEventHandler = (s, f) => ComputeVisibleItemsCount(itemsControl);

   var treeListView = AssociatedObject as TreeListView;        
   treeListView.SizeChanged += _sizeChangedEventHandler;

   itemsControl.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
}
```

These events gets called when I load my app and when I resize my treeview. My problem is in the calculation of visible items inside the treeview. Unfortunately the IsVisible property doesnot give me a correct result. I used the answer suggested in [In WPF, how can I determine whether a control is visible to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517743/in-wpf-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-control-is-visible-to-the-user)

But that does not seems to work for me. It gives me a wrong result.

Any good practice or standard solution to determine the actual viewable items in a itemscontrol ? when resizing and scrolling ? By the way I'm using reactive collection for my treeview items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution. Anyone is welcome to refactor and correct the code.

```
[Localizable(false)]
public class ItemsControlResizingBehavior : Behavior<ItemsControl>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibleItemsCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VisibleItemsCount",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(ItemsControlResizingBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, OnSizeChanged));

    public int VisibleItemsCount
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(VisibleItemsCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VisibleItemsCountProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnSizeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == null)
            return;
        var behavior = (ItemsControlResizingBehavior)d;

        if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null)
            return;

        behavior.ComputeVisibleItemsCount(behavior.AssociatedObject);
    }

    private SizeChangedEventHandler _listViewSizeChangedEventHandler;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsControl = (ItemsControl)sender;

        _listViewSizeChangedEventHandler = (x, y) => ComputeVisibleItemsCount(itemsControl);

        var treeListView = AssociatedObject as TreeListView;
        if (treeListView != null)
            treeListView.SizeChanged += _listViewSizeChangedEventHandler;

        var listView = AssociatedObject as ListView;
        if (listView != null)
            listView.SizeChanged += _listViewSizeChangedEventHandler;

        itemsControl.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        var treeListView = AssociatedObject as TreeListView;
        if (treeListView != null)
            treeListView.SizeChanged -= _listViewSizeChangedEventHandler;

        var listView = AssociatedObject as ListView;
        if (listView != null)
            listView.SizeChanged -= _listViewSizeChangedEventHandler;
    }

    private void ComputeVisibleItemsCount(ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
        if (itemsControl.Items.Count <= 0)
            return;

        if (itemsControl is TreeListView)
        {
            VisibleItemsCount = GetTreeViewItems(itemsControl).Count(x => x.IsVisibleInUI(itemsControl));
        }
        if (itemsControl is ListView)
        {
            VisibleItemsCount = GetListViewItems(itemsControl).Count(x => x.IsVisibleInUI(itemsControl));
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TreeViewItem> GetTreeViewItems(ItemsControl tree)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = (TreeViewItem)tree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (item == null)
                continue;

            yield return item;

            foreach (TreeViewItem subItem in GetTreeViewItems(item))
            {
                yield return subItem;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ListViewItem> GetListViewItems(ItemsControl list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = (ListViewItem)list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (item == null)
                continue;

            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```