# Detect when WPF control moves relative to its parent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, optimization

I know how to find control's location relative to its parent via the [TransformToAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608865%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and there's even a way to determine [whether the control is visible to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517743/in-wpf-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-control-is-visible-to-the-user) based on that transform.

Now I need to detect *changes* in control's location. Let's ignore effects and visual transforms for now to keep things simple. All I need is monitoring changes in [Visual.VisualOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is not a dependency property and there is no associated change event.

Visual.VisualOffset seems to be only updated during arrange phase. Perhaps [UIElement.LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event could provide me with the right notification. But then it's a global event with no parameters. I would have to iterate all monitored visuals whenever anything changes. Such iteration would have to be done up to 60 times per second whenever user drags something.

I wonder whether there's something less invasive that won't force me to recheck all visuals globally.

Here's an example. Look at [LazyControl](https://bitbucket.org/robertvazan/junglecontrols/src/343c4bc09fcd748568b514598f0aa7def73a0304/JungleControls/LazyControl.cs?at=default) source. Method `IsInView` performs the check using `TransformToAncestor`. I need to call this method every time something changes that the method depends on.

Comment: You said "This is not a dependency property", but why not just make a dependency property for it, and bind the control's Top/Left properties to that dependency property?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott What do you mean by Top/Left? This is not about Canvas. This is about general visual tree. You cannot just patch dependency property on top of existing class. It won't sync with the real property.

Comment: Could you show us some code? ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could the [`CompositionTarget.Rendering` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering(v=vs.110).aspx") provide a better place to check the visual you want to monitor?

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop That event is actually fired more often than LayoutUpdated.

Comment: @RobertVažan Not necessarily, although this doesn't give a good explanation, it might be of use: [link](http://evanl.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/efficient-optimal-per-frame-eventing-in-wpf/)

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop My measurements show 40 LayoutUpdate calls/second when user drags scrollbar. Rendering event with its (estimated) 60fps can be faster only if LayoutUpdate is called cyclically (due to tree changes while in LayoutUpdate), but then that seems to be the case with Rendering event too. When do you think it could be faster?

Comment: @RobertVažan [FrameworkElement.LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layoutupdated(v=vs.95).aspx) : `LayoutUpdated can occur when the object where the handler is attached does not necessarily change anything in the visual tree under it. For instance, imagine a layout container where there are two elements. If the first object changes a property that forces a new layout, both objects raise LayoutUpdated because the second object might be repositioned even if its own subsidiary layout does not change.`

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop Rendering event is raised shortly afterwards, and, if both objects subscribe, both of them will receive the Rendering notification. Is it your point that Rendering event is global? LayoutUpdated can be easily made global by creating one global UIElement and subscribing to its LayoutUpdated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59338/discussion-between-roel-van-westerop-and-robert-vazan).

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding [UIElement.OnRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Is this event triggered on descendant control tree during scrolling? I think scrolling skips it and instead simply updates visual offset of the whole scrolled area.