# find Visible controls on Flowlayoutpanel (Client area ) C#

Tags: c#, .net, flowlayoutpanel

Basically i have a scrollable form holding Flowlayoutpanel and Flowlayoutpanel has multiple pictureboxes on it . When Flowlayoutpanel's area increases beyond the client area of the form after inserting multiple Pictureboxes , Scrollbar comes in to picture.

When i scroll down i want to find out what are the visible controls.

Any idea how to find out this one ?

Comment: Is this something that will be done in code behind?  Are you looking for a function you can call explicitly that will return a list of visible PictureBoxes?

Comment: @ Jason , I am looking for .Net Api if any or custom logic to do the same.

Comment: It sounds like this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1517794/1937249.  You can iterate over each picture box passing it and the FlowLayoutPanel to the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In WPF, how can I determine whether a control is visible to the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517743/in-wpf-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-control-is-visible-to-the-user)