# Using WPF ItemsControl Virtualization to load data only for visible items

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization

We have an ItemsControl setup like this

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

with the MainViewModel being:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<AutoUpdatingItem> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<AutoUpdatingItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new AutoUpdatingItem(i));
        }
    }
}
```

and the ViewModel of the row

```
public class AutoUpdatingItem : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;

    private int data;
    public int Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { Set(ref data, value); }
    }

    public AutoUpdatingItem(int i)
    {
        Data = i;
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Data would be fetched from WebService here
        Data++;
    }
}
```

How can we achieve that only the visible items are updated? Is there any way to get notified when an item in the virtualized panel is being recycled?

Comment: I'd bind 'IsVisibly' property and based on that start/stop timer when it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (see: [In WPF, how can I determine whether a control is visible to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517743/in-wpf-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-control-is-visible-to-the-user)):

```
public class AutoUpdatingItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;

    private int data;
    public int Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set 
        { 
            data = value; 
            propertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Data))); 
        }
    }

    public AutoUpdatingItem()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,200), DispatcherPriority.Background, Tick, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Data++;
    }

    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            propertyChanged += value;
            timer.Start();
        }
        remove
        {
            timer.Stop();
            propertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

With the following XAML:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Height="500">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border >
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                  CanContentScroll="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
```